# PWM driven power supply

Tags: power, pwm, control, load

As you have asked me, I will explain in better words my problem.
I'm working on real-time bench. I have an algorithm on my laptop and I interact with hardware through a calculator supporting real-time testing.
My main goal is to test things and see how they work in different situations.
I have a tank filled with a liquid. I have a heater which is a resistance that drains maximum 7.08A at 12V. The ambient temperature and the heating temperature , in my algorithm, are inputs or outputs for 2 other less powerful heaters and a pump. The idea being that my pump, by varying its speed, changes other variables (like temperature, pressure or level in the tank or in the line) and those variables change the input of the heater and how it behaves. Or by changing some sensor signals in my software, making the heater behave differently. That's what I meant by "varying a lot".

Now, my problem is that the heater that I want drive drains more current and is more powerful than the output of my calculator can afford. My PWM output pin can give 5A and 12V signal which is not enough for my heater. So I thought about a DC power supply which is able to give the heater the right amount of power, that takes the PWM outputted by my calculator and drives its own DC voltage output with it to bear with the heater voltage or current variations.

Finally, my question is : Is this idea feasible ? Can I solve my problem with a different way ?

Thank you for your time and have a nice day.

Landau

Comment: What exactly is the one thing you are asking about?  At first it seems the problem is controlling 90 W from a 60 W controller, but you babble on about PWM.  Then you say it's about the power supply. *What* power supply? Is *what* theoretically possible?  Closing until you produce a coherent question.

Comment: Is there any reason why you want variable voltage out of your power supply, rather than just PWM?

Comment: @Olin Lathrop Thank you for your intervention. Sorry if I have bothered you. Could you help me by explaining to me how I could post an image, so I can be more clear in my question ?

Comment: Your not giving us much information on the type of heating system or the proposed power supply.  In short, if you happen to have a simple resistive heating element then you might be able to directly power it with the PWM signal to achieve a 0 to 60w output.  Without more info it is not clear if this would work.

Comment: @Simon B,@Nedd : The heating system in a simple resistive one. I can achieve a PWM output from 0 to 60W but my heater draws 90W and varies a lot because it is part of a bigger system with different actuators. Can you please ask me for the information that you need ?

Comment: @Landau: (1) How to post an image: click the image button on the editor in your question. (2) How to add a schematic: click on the schematic button on the editor.

Comment: @Landau you're hinting at a rather complex system, without giving us any real details.  If the heater is a simple resistor, how does it "vary a lot"?  What have the actuators got to do with any of this?  We could do with a block diagram at least, and some basic specifications besides wattages (voltages and whether it's AC or DC at least).  I suspect you're actually over-complicating the question with extraneous details that aren't relevant, but we can't tell.

Comment: @Landau: Please **edit your question** and include the following information: (1) Power of heater. (90 W?) (2) Voltage of heater. (3) Supply voltage. AC or DC? (4) Rough response time of heater. e.g. 1°C in 22 s. (5) Do you have a controller or is this a new design? (6) Why are you not using a commercial temperature controller. i.e., What's special about this process?

Comment: I have edited my question. I hope it is more clear.

Comment: @Landau I'm coming to the conclusion that Gregory Kornblum has the right answer.  If you have a power supply beefy enough to power the heater, then use a simple transistor switch between the power supply and the heater, and switch the transistor on and off using the PWM output of your controller.

Comment: @SimonB Thank you for your answer. I will investigate this solution and come back to you if I have further questions. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a heater there is a good chance that you can take just a common dc supply and use a MOSFET to pwm it's output with low frequency of even 1Hz. Or 10Hz. Anyway, its a heater, you don't have to filternthe wave, etc. And the system response is very slow compared to other pwm usages.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Gregory. The output pwmed could drive the heater ? I'm sorry if i misunderstood you.

Comment: Yes. The other words are to overcome 15 characters minimum

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're comparing at the exact same voltages, it's a bad idea to try to drive a 90W heater with a supply capable of only 60W. Probably it will current-limit during the PWM cycles and may do even less desirable things.

It's possible you could make a buck regulator that would provide a maximum of 60W to the load- you would need to reduce the voltage by a minimum of \$\sqrt{\frac{60}{90}}\$ = 18% (minus a bit more for the regulator losses) and control that (for example, by a series switch).

So if your supply was 24V and the heater was 6.4 ohms and you reduce the voltage to 18V you'll have about 50W available to drive the '90W' heater, and can run at 100% PWM if you like.

You could just throw the voltage away in a resistor but then you'd have as much as 20W to get rid of in the resistor, and you'd only have 40W available at the heater.